# Test case for vestingWallet smart contract returning "header not found"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, openzeppelin

network,

I've been trying to finish a unit test for an investing wallet smart contract on Solidity as mentioned above:

The idea is to create a test cenarium for a vesting wallet smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/VestingWallet.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract VestingContract is VestingWallet {
    constructor(
        address beneficiaryAddress,
        uint64 startTimestamp,
        uint64 durationSeconds
    )
        public
        VestingWallet(beneficiaryAddress, startTimestamp, durationSeconds)
    {}

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getBalanceFromToken(address _token) public view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
}
```

and I also created these tests.

```
const VestingContract = artifacts.require("VestingContract");
const IoraContract = artifacts.require("Iora");

contract("VestingContract", function (accounts) {

  it("should assert true", async function () {
    await VestingContract.deployed();
    return assert.isTrue(true);
  });

  it("beneficiary and accounts[0] should be the same", async function () {

    const wallet = accounts[0];
    const vestingInstance = await VestingContract.deployed();
    const walletFromSmartContract = await vestingInstance.beneficiary();

    return assert.isTrue(wallet === walletFromSmartContract)
  });

  it("actual timestamp should be the high or the same when it was deployed", async function () {

    const vestingInstance = await VestingContract.deployed();
    const vestingStarted = await vestingInstance.start();
    const startTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    return assert.isTrue(startTimestamp >= vestingStarted.toNumber())
  });

  it("balance from erc20 token should be the same on this contract balance", async function () {

    const vestingInstance = await VestingContract.deployed();
    const ioraInstance = await IoraContract.deployed();
    await ioraInstance.transfer(vestingInstance.address, 150);
    const ioraBalance = await ioraInstance.balanceOf(vestingInstance.address);
    const ioraTokenBalance = await vestingInstance.getBalanceFromToken(ioraInstance.address);

    return assert.isTrue(ioraBalance.toNumber() === ioraTokenBalance.toNumber())
  });

  it("total released should be the same as we transfered", async function () {

    const amount = 3000;
    const vestingInstance = await VestingContract.deployed();
    const ioraInstance = await IoraContract.deployed();
    await ioraInstance.transfer(vestingInstance.address, amount);

    await vestingInstance.release(ioraInstance.address);
    const releasedVesting = await vestingInstance.released(vestingInstance.address);

    return assert.isTrue(amount === releasedVesting.toNumber())

  });

});
```

but, I'm getting this error:

```
  1) Contract: VestingContract
       total released should be the same as we transfered:
     Error: Returned error: header not found
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/vesting_contract.js:47:51)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

My question is, why my header was not found and also how can I solve it?

Comment: Seems like issue with the node that your test is connected to. Are you using local emulator (e.g. Ganache by Truffle) or some third-party provider connected to a public network? https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/7234, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71311931/1693192

Comment: Hi @PetrHejda! Yes, I'm using ganache with the command `npx ganache`. I will try to use another node.